# After moving to WSL, Selenium is no longer working. Due to SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The version of WSL I am using is WSL2 and I am using Ubuntu for WSL.
`selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities`
Is the error that I get whenever I try to run the python file. Here is the code within the file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://www.google.com"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
```

I've tried this code outside of WSL, and it works. I can't get it to work on WSL and geckodriver is in my PATH.